# Feedback Vertex Set

Tags: algorithm, graph, parameters, set, vertex

I have a question regarding the problem known by the name of
Feedback Vertex Set.

In Feedback Vertex Set, we are given an undirected graph G and k ∈ N, and the objective is to decide whether there exists a subset S ⊆ V (G) of size at most k such that G − S is a forest.

I need to design a:

A. w^{O(w)}n^{O(1)} time algorithm for the problem where w is the treewidth.

B. k^{O(\sqrt k)}n^{O(1)} time algorithm for the problem on planar graphs.

I'm struggling to understand how i can connect between the treewidth with the deletion of the vertices.

Thank you

Comment: This is more of a [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) question, but the short version is that you want to run a dynamic program on the tree decomposition, and the smaller the width, the fewer states and hence shorter running time.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat can you describe this dynamic programming

Comment: It's in here somewhere: https://planarity.org/